# Erro No Phpmyadmin - erro ao selecionar o Auto Increment

Tags: php

Toda vez que eu tento selecionar o Auto Increment numa tabela acontece isso aqui -

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só pode ter um campo único de auto incremento, como o próprio erro indica. Por isso deve estar a tentar modificar/adicionar um campo com auto incremento quando já tem um

Comment: Antes de clicar em "Guarda" clica em "Pré visualizar SQL" e poste a expressão sql na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Como dito no erro e no comentário do Isac, **só pode ter um campo `auto-increment`.**

Você **pode sim ter outras chaves primárias e/ou estrangeiras**, dependendo da sua necessidade.

---

Pelo print, provavelmente o campo `id` dessa tabela `usuarios` seja `auto-increment`.

Para confirmar, clique em cima e terá o flag do `auto-increment`:

[image: flag]

---

Caso queira alterar para a nova coluna que está criando, desmarque-o, e crie outro campo com o flag marcado.